# On conditions to prove that a Lie group is compact.

Tags: lie-groups

Can anyone help me with this problem:
If *G* is a Lie group and *H* a compact subgoup of *G*, such that *G/H* is also compact, how to prove that G is compact?
I have tried to push forward an open covering of *G* to *G/H* be the quotient map, apply compactness and then pull it back, but there are subtle accommodations that should be made and I can not figure out how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need the Tube Lemma.  Do you have this?

Comment: I'm reading it now, how should I apply it?. I even tried to construct a continuous function from *HxG/H* to G but I didn't figure out how.

Comment: The argument is long.  First, do you believe that (a) the quotient map $q: G \rightarrow G/H$ is a closed map and (b) that $CK$ is closed whenever $C$ is closed and $K$ is compact (all in $G$)?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root idea:  take an open cover 
$$
G = \bigcup_{\alpha} U_\alpha.
$$
Since $H$ is compact, so is every coset $gH$.  So, $G$ can be partitioned into compact components, so to speak. And, note that the quotient space $G/H$ is also compact, by assumption.

So, each coset $gH$ is also covered by the same covering, but by compactness you only need a finite number of them.  Denote this cover by 
$$
\mathcal{U}_g = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n_g} U_{\alpha_i}^g
$$
where I hope it is somehow clear that every $U_{\alpha_i}^g$ is one of the original $U_\alpha$'s.  (There may very well be better notation and indexing, but I'm in a hurry.)

As $gH \subseteq \mathcal{U}_g$ and $q$ is a closed map there is an open set $W_g$ in $G/H$ such that $q^{-1}(W_g) \subseteq \mathcal{U}_g$.  Now $\bigcup_{g \in G} W_g$ covers $G/H$ and by compactness this can be done finitely:
$$
G/H = \bigcup_{i=1}^r W_{g_i}.
$$
Now, if you take the preimage under $q$ of both sides you get
$$
G = \bigcup_{i=1}^r q^{-1}(W_{g_i}).
$$
But now we have 
$$
G = \bigcup_{i=1}^r q^{-1}(W_{g_i}) \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^r \mathcal{U}_{g_i} = \bigcup_{i=1}^r \bigcup_{k=1}^{n_{g_i}} U_{\alpha_k}^{g_i}.
$$
This last union is a finite one derived from the original cover, so $G$ is compact.